# Use printf to output string from specific letter/symbol

Tags: bash, printf

I'm actually using this:

```
string=$(printf '%%.160s\n...' "<line_from_syslog>")
```

Which outputs something like:

```
Dec 7 09:27:29 srv-beta dr(example.com)[23902]: Authentication attempt for unknown user tdomf_384d7#profilepage from 1.2.3.4
```

I would like to change that `printf` to output starting after the `]:`, so it only outputs

```
Authentication attempt for unknown user tdomf_384d7#profilepage from 1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Is the line from syslog in a variable? If it is, you could use `"${linevar#*\]:}"` to trim it.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple way the use of `Awk` can be done

As per the block of code given by you, it can be converted as:

`string=$(printf '%%.160s\n...' "<line_from_syslog>" | awk -F]:\  '{print $2}')`

there may be more easy method than this.